# Eclipse Luna Indexer for C++14 with custom makefile

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, c++14

I currently have a C++ project with a custom makefile. I tell eclipse to simply call make and the makefile handles everything. The project builds fine but eclipse keeps highlighting generalized lambda captures as "syntax errors". As far as I understand from this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/835019/4076418 ,

it's a problem with the CDT Indexer not understanding the C++14 syntax.

I've tried following the answers here:

[Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9131763/4076418)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635080/4076418

but they don't handle my case which is Eclipse Luna + a custom makefile project + c++14.

This question is probably related to mine but it has no answer [I also don't have the ability to change the indexer]:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/24950192/4076418

Any ideas on how to get the indexer to recognize c++14 features?

P.S. C++11 features aren't highlighted as syntax errors for some reason. I should also note that I'm using clang 3.4.2 in the makefile; obviously, it supports c++14. The g++ version available though is 4.4.7 so it doesn't support c++14. Could this be the problem somehow? That the CDT uses the system's g++ for the indexer? And if so, how do I change that without having to update g++ (I'm working with limited user privileges and updating it would be a pain)?

Comment: Great. I messed up my configuration even more. It used to recognize c++11 features. Now, it even highlights things like std::vector.

I give up...

Comment: Have you tried adding `-std=c++14` to the compiler flags in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Eclipse Luna does not support C++14 overall. You will probably need to upgrade to Eclipse Neon. I use neon, the parser works, I don't use custom makefile though

I have used Luna in the past, but even C++11 support was sometimes hard to setup.